# Swift 4 Camera NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: swift, camera

I had my custom camera functioning in swift 3 but when I updated it I tried to change it to work with what works now

Code Before:

```
func photoOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, previewPhoto previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings: AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

  if let unwrappedError = error {
      print(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)
  } else {

      if let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer, let dataImage = AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer: sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewPhotoSampleBuffer) {

        if let finalImage = UIImage(data: dataImage) {
         let newImage = finalImage.resizeImage(image: finalImage)
         let place = CGPoint(x: newImage.size.width / 2, y: newImage.size.height/2)
Make sure point is within the image
        let color = newImage.getPixelColor(pos: place)
        print(color)
       displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto: finalImage)
    }
   }
  }
}
```

Changed Code: (Doesn't Work)

```
    private func photoOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    if let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
        if let finalImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {
        let newImage = finalImage.resizeImage(image: finalImage)
        let place = CGPoint(x: newImage.size.width / 2, y: newImage.size.height/2)
        let color = newImage.getPixelColor(pos: place)
        print(color)
        displayCapturedPhoto(capturedPhoto: finalImage)
    }
    }
}
```

I keep getting the error as follows:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCapturePhotoOutput capturePhotoWithSettings:delegate:] If you specify a non-nil format dictionary in your settings, your delegate must respond to the selector captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhoto:error:, or the deprecated captureOutput:didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer:previewPhotoSampleBuffer:resolvedSettings:bracketSettings:error:

Any ideas?

Comment: try `func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
        
        if let error = error {
            print("Error:", error)
        } else {
            let imageData = photo.fileDataRepresentation()
        }
    }`

Comment: Thanks that worked!